# VSCode does not load .js file in <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, permissions, script-tag

I'm  working on setting up my dev machine to do Electron development in VS Code.

I've been following a Hello World sample.

The problem is that the .js file inside a  tag isn't being loaded. I put an alert() in an inline tag in the same html file and the alert fired correctly.

When I debug, the index.js file isn't being loaded at all.

This is my main.js

```
    const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron')
    const path = require('path')
    const url = require('url')
    const shell = require('electron').shell
    let win 
    function createWindow () {
    win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600})
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname,'src/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
        }))
    // win.webContents.openDevTools()
    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
        })
    var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: 'File',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Sign In To SL',
                    click() {
                        shell.openExternal('https://stackoverflow.com')
                    }
                },
                {type: 'separator'},
                { 
                    label: 'Exit',
                    click() { app.quit() }
                }
            ]
        }
            
        ]
    )
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
    }
    app.on('ready', createWindow)
    app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
      if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
    })
    app.on('activate', () => {ok
        if (win == null) {
            createWindow()
        }
})
```

This is the HTML for index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
        <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">-->
       <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">-->
        <title>Souper Grouper</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="userinfo-container">
            <p class="subtext">User Name:</p>
            <h1 id="username">Not Signed In</h1>
          </div>
          <div id="signin-container">
            <button id="signinBtn">Sign In</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
      </body>
</html>
```

This is index.js

```
    const electron = require('electron')
    const path = require('path')
    const BrowserWindow = electron.remote.BrowserWindow
    const signinBtn = document.getElementById('signinBtn')
    signinBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        alert("fired")    
        const modalPath = path.join('file://', __dirname, 'signin.html')
        let win = new BrowserWindow({ frame: false, width: 400, height: 200})
        win.on('close', function() { win = null})
        win.loadURL(modalPath)
        win.show()
})
```

I've double checked the VSCode Trust Center and the folder above my App is Trusted.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try adding the attribute type="module" to be certain it loads after the DOM has.
Also looks like you're using npm imports not JS imports, are you using a transpiler at all?

Comment: Thank you. I tried the type="module" tag. No change. I haven't found much information on transpiler, so I'm sure at all. I using VSCode, on Electron writing javascript (not TypeScript). I'm really just working a simple app, one step up from "Hello World" to verify my development environment.